# Quais tags devem entrar para a lista negra?

Tags: debate, big-7, tags

Temos algumas tags que são usadas **sempre** de forma equivocada, são usadas para indicar algo que não deveria ser nosso objetivo ou funciona como uma meta-tag.

Algumas dessas tags deveriam ser banidas e seu uso proibido porque **nunca** acrescentam alguma coisa à pergunta.

Quais seriam as tags que devem ser proibidas?

Vou dar alguns exemplos para discutir mas **não** estou sugerindo formalmente que todas elas sejam proibidas.

[iniciantes](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/iniciantes), [aprendizagem](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/aprendizagem), [aprendizagem-programação](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/aprendizagem-programa%c3%a7%c3%a3o), [web](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/web), e domínios específicos [cifra-musical](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/cifra-musical), [nome-civil](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/nome-civil), etc.

Comment: Acho que todas essas que você citou poderiam ser banidas. Mas pra falar a verdade, nem sei como funciona isso. É possível impedir algumas tags de serem adicionadas?

Comment: @utluiz Tem algumas formas de fazer isso.

Comment: seria o caso de fazer que nem no tópico do on-topic de cada um postar como wiki um unico assunto por resposta? tem que justificar? ainda é pra valer esse tópico aqui?

Answer (score 2):

Algumas tags ao invés de acrescentar à pergunta podem ser utilizadas para separá-las e facilitar a pesquisa. Talvez o mais difícil seja diferenciar os dois casos.

Não acredito que uma tag ser mal utilizada deva ser o motivo para impedir seu uso. Mas uma tag ser tão abrangente que seja impossível diferenciar sobre o que está falando sim.

Como exemplo:

Se a tag [aprendizagem](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/aprendizagem) fosse utilizada para o assunto da pergunta, então não acho que deva ser banida. Mas se o autor colocou a tag porque é o objetivo dele aprender ou o estado dele (ele estar aprendendo), daí a coisa muda de figura. Afinal, de modo geral, sempre que fazemos uma pergunta gostaríamos de aprender algo.